# How to fix lock error with AT command?

Tags: command-line

When I execute this :

```
at 7:43 -f atfile.sh
```

I get this :

```
warning: commands will be executed using /bin/sh
Cannot open lockfile /var/spool/cron/atjobs/.SEQ: No such file or directory
```

So what I'm doing wrong? What's wrong with the command?

How do I fix this error?

Comment: I found this http://salinelinux.proboards.com/thread/248 that solved the problem

Comment: so the link is dead and you didn't provide explanations ... not funny!

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

The warning comes up when the user's shell is not `/usr/bin/sh`.  So just change your login shell to `/usr/bin/sh`.

Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
chsh -s /bin/sh $USER
```

Comment: I get the same error through bash or bourne shells on CentOS 6.7